# How do I change the download location of a file which is currently being downloaded with Firefox?

Tags: windows, windows-10, firefox, download, file-download

Lets say that a 2 GB file is being downloaded to `C:\Users\user\Downloads\` but the C:\ drive only has 1 GB of storage space left. The D:\ drive has 10 GB of storage space free, so I want to change the files from being downloaded to `C:\Users\user\Downloads\file.mp4` and `C:\Users\user\Downloads\file.mp4.part` and instead be downloaded to `D:\user\Documents\D\a\file.mp4` and `D:\user\Documents\D\a\file.mp4.part` without having to restart the entire download which is mostly done.

How would I do this?

I tried using a program called junction for Windows 10 to change them into symbolic link files, but that program only works for folders, empty folders, or files which do not exist yet (example command: 'junction "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update" "D:\user\Documents\ChromeBlows\ProgramFilesx86\Update"'). I downloaded junction form https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/junction.

I thought that I commanded my computer to download to a directory in D:\ but somehow it ended up going to a C:\ directory

Answer (score 1):

Change the file location once the download has *started*, "without having to restart the entire download?" Can't be done.

However, if you right-click a link to a file and *Save Link As...*, the download can be set to any accessible location.

[image: How to Save As]

Answer (score 0):

From [support.mozilla.org](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/where-find-and-manage-downloaded-files-firefox#w_change-where-downloads-are-saved)

Change where downloads are saved

File downloads are saved in the folder specified in Firefox Options . To change that folder:

1. Click the menu button and select Options
2. In the General panel, find the Downloads section under Files and Applications.
3. Click the Browsebutton next to the Save files to entry.
4. Choose the downloads folder you wish to use.

Hope it helps!!!